# componentDidMount() async background-image

Tags: reactjs

React Newbee here

**Firstly ,** I have a component `DetailMovieCard.jsx` where I am inserting background image in `componentDidMount ()` It works fine but I was wondering is there any other efficient way instead of using 
`document.body.style.backgroundImage`

DetailMovieCard.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Glyphicon, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { URL_IMAGE, URL_BACKGROUND } from "../const";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden; `;

const Image = styled.img`
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
`;

class DetailMovieCard extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate() {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage =
`url(${URL_BACKGROUND}${this.props.movie.backdrop_path})`;}

    render() {
        const {
            poster_path, original_title, backdrop_path, tagline, overview,
        } = this.props.movie;

        return (
            <Wrapper>
                <Image alt="" src={`${URL_IMAGE}${poster_path}`} />
                <div className="movie-details">
                    <h3>Title of the movie is {original_title} </h3>
                    <div>
                        <div className="movie-tagline"> {tagline} </div>
                        <div className="movie-overview">{overview} </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Wrapper>
        );
    }    
}

export default DetailMovieCard;
```

**Secondly** , I have a component called MovieDetails.jsx currently I am giving data fetched by `componentDidMount()` directly to `<DetailMovieCard movie={this.state.movieData} >` again it works fine but is there any better way of doing it ?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { URL_DETAIL, API_KEY } from "../const";
import DetailMovieCard from './DetailMovieCard';
import Header from './Header';

class MovieDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            movieData: { movies: " " }
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        axios.get(`${URL_DETAIL}${id}${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ movieData: response.data });
            });}

    render() {
        return (
            <div className= "movie-container">
                <Header/>
                <DetailMovieCard movie={this.state.movieData} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default MovieDetails;
```

Comment: You'd better split this into 2 questions.

Comment: Both of them are inter-related  , Can you shed some light ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use callbacks:

- Set the `backgroundImage` in your main App component there is no reason to use `<body>`
- Keep the current `backgroundImage url` in main App component state or in redux store
- Then you can set the `backgroundImage url` using regular javascript callbacks

Comment: how can I get the url link in `App.jsx` for the background image as its coming from parent component `MovieDetails.jsx`  i.e : `this.props.movie.backdrop_path`

Comment: I am not using redux , its just reactjs

Comment: 1) You will have something like `this.state.backgroundImage` in your main component 2) Then your main component will have a handler that will update the background color. Something like: `changeBackgroundColor(newBackgroundColor)` 3) You need to pass the `changeBackgroundColor` in props to your child components. 4) If you have too many levels you can use context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: when you say main component is it `App.jsx` ?

Comment: Yes that should be the main component :)